# Why isn't my report header showing up in production?

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that pulls 2 datasets from the same data source.

- One is used to build a tablix.
- One is used to build the report name.  (We reference the report name in many documents and this keeps them in sync.)

To be clear, I call a stored procedure to fetch each dataset.  The first stored procedure is report data, the second stored procedure only pulls one row with report number, report name, and report description.

Works fine in Visual Studio.  When I put on the server, the report header isn't displayed.

To expedite the editing process for 200 reports, I set the report header data set up in one report, then cut and pasted the XML into the dataset structure for all other reports.  A lot quicker than setting up the same using the VS GUI.

IF I RUN THE REPORT on the report server, it works just fine as well.

Only when I try to hit it from the web does it fail.

Comment: Difficult to know without seeing what the RDL looks like, so all I can suggest is that you download the RDL from the Web Portal and then open that RDL in VS to compare to the original version. If the reports rely on default parameter values, try deleting the deployed reports and redeploying as parameter defaults are not overwritten when you deploy an update to an existing report.

Answer (score 0):

Report Parameter is 'rpt011', 'rpt022', etc.  This is fed by the calling program.  I display this tidbit in the page footer, so I know it's there, and being passed in.

Second dataset takes a 3 character string (report #) as the parameter to the stored procedure which returns the report name.  Works fine in Visual Studio, works fine when I'm on the report server, but fails when called from the web.

Makes no sense, but

> =Replace(Parameters!rpt.Value, "rpt", "")

does not work in all environments.

> =Right(Parameters!rpt.Value, 3)

does work in all environments.  Makes zero sense.

My manager will now give me milk and cookies.